# When the value is empty, I want to print something else on a page

Tags: php

I have a simple code that I want when the name of a bank is empty and a site binlist has not obtained it from a database that writes something else in its place, for example : N/A

```
$BIN  = str_replace(' ', '',$PCT);
$BIN  = substr($BIN, 0, 6);
$url = "https://lookup.binlist.net/" . $BIN;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$details = json_decode($resp, true);
$countryname = strtoupper($details['country']['name']);
$cardtype = ucwords($details['type']);
$cardbrand = ucwords($details['brand']);
$bankname = strtoupper($details['bank']['name']);
$_SESSION['bankname'] = $bankname;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you asking if `$resp` is empty or `$details['bank']['name']`, or both?

Comment: @user3783243 I tried and it didn't work. I just want when the name of a bank is empty. Print something else in its place on the next page for example : N/A

Comment: Where do you want to print it, you don't print anything with this code? Do you want `$bankname` to be `N/A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply check if it empty and assign the value in this case?

For example:

`$bankname = empty($details['bank']['name']) ? 'N/A' : strtoupper($details['bank']['name']);`